# How to use FEC data to search for campaign contributions from a list of people?

Tags: openfec

If one had a list of campaign contributors and wanted to generate a document listing all of their historical campaign contributions from the FEC data, without having to query each name individually, how would one do that?

Note: my own coding skills are slight, so while a technical answer is good, even better would be a pointer to some utility that someone has already developed to do this. (Worst case, some advice for extracting the data from the FEC's bulk downloads in a non-clunky fashion would work.)

Comment: opensecrets is easier, imo, but you still need to do manual for each, if you don't/can't code it. https://www.opensecrets.org/indivs/index.php

Comment: @albert, this would be good as an answer.